# Batch File Replace Semicolon with Quotes

Tags: batch-file, quotes

I have a csv file in certain location and I would like to replace all semicolon with quotes using some batch file.

Can you please advice ?

Matus

Comment: Sure! Here my advice: https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html Learn to code batch.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do a replacement directly into the file itself, you can get the variables, do the replacement and then write to a newfile. You can also move the newfile name to the old if you like.

This example reads the file, replaces semicolon with double quotes and writes to `newfile.txt`

```
@Echo off
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
For /f "delims=*" %%a in (myfile.csv) do (set "var=%%a"
 Set var=!var:;="!
 Echo !var! >> newfile.txt
)
Endlocal
```